# Google Sheets - Script to add dynamic borders until last non-empty row of range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that shows a user's ranking in a competition that runs each week.  As users enter the competition, a new row of data is added to the 'Weekly Leaderboard' C9:E20 range.

I am trying to create a google sheets script to add left/right/vertical borders to data within the C9:E20 range until the last row of data.

The last row of data will have left/right/vertical/bottom borders to close up the table.

Sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ediNmkk-aqBvxidr6CFmGl0BIfzTHzGF6pCSziuYPAM/edit#gid=0

Pictures below:

[Picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPm8v.png)

[GOAL: Add left/right/center border to range with data, bottom border for last row with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJW21.png)

Hoping that is enough of a description. Please let me know if any questions.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation from `The number of participants can be less or more each week, so the function will have to erase any pre-existing bordering each time it runs. Likely onEdit.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: The borders need to be dynamic, so if there is data in C9:E13 one week....  and then the next week there is data in C9:E18.  Then the previous borders need to be erased, and then replaced with the new borders.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the relationship between `The data in range C9:E20 is dynamic based on how many participants. So if there is 3 rows of data one week (C9:E12), it could be 12 the next week` and OnEdit?

Comment: Sure! The data in C9:E20 is constantly updating.  So as more rows of data are added in the C9:E20 range, I would like the function to add borders.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike - Thanks so much for your solution, that's what I was looking for!  I will mark this solved, but I have a question for you.  Is there a better trigger other than onEdit for this solution?  I only suggested onEdit because of my brief script experience. If there is an alternative/more productive method, please let me know and I can try a different way.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `Is there a better trigger other than onEdit for this solution?`, when you want to run the script when a cell is edited, I think that OnEdit trigger is suitable. Because `onEdit` can be run as a simple trigger, and also, in this case, it is not required to manually install the trigger. The function name of `onEdit` is used as the simple trigger of OnEdit. So I thought that this method will be suitable. If this was not your expected answer to your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. This has been very helpful and insightful.  Have a great day :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your question, the simple trigger `onEdit` can be used. As an important point, `onEdit` of a simple trigger has a limitation. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) For example, it cannot be used for all methods of Google Apps Script. For example, when you want to use another Spreadsheet and you want to send an email, it is required to use the installable OnEdit trigger. I thought that such information might be useful for your future development.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike - Apologies if I need to start a new question for this.  I failed to mention that the data in cells C9:E20 are referenced from a different tab. ('Weekly Selections' A7:A19).  So when the values change in the Weekly Selections tab, the OnEdit function doesn't pick up the change.  Is there a way to adjust the script to run the exact same border check on C9:E20 if there is an edit to range 'Weekly Selections' A7:A19?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I failed to mention that the data in cells C9:E20 are referenced from a different tab. ('Weekly Selections' A7:A19). So when the values change in the Weekly Selections tab, the OnEdit function doesn't pick up the change. Is there a way to adjust the script to run the exact same border check on C9:E20 if there is an edit to range 'Weekly Selections' A7:A19?`. But I would like to support you. So in this case, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the cells "C9:E20" of "Weekly Leaderboard" sheet are edited, you want to set the borders in the sheet.
- You want to achieve this using OnEdit trigger when the cells are edited.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Weekly Leaderboard"; // This is from your provided Spreadsheet.
  const expectedRange = "C9:E20"; // This is from your question.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName) return;
  const r = sheet.getRange(expectedRange);
  const startRow = r.getRow();
  const endRow = startRow + r.getNumRows() - 1;
  const startCol = r.getColumn();
  const endCol = startCol + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
  if (range.rowStart < startRow || range.rowEnd > endRow || range.columnStart < startCol || range.columnEnd > endCol) return;
  r.setBorder(null, false, false, false, false, false);
  const last = r.getDisplayValues().findIndex(rr => !rr.join(""));
  sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, last != -1 ? last : r.getNumRows(), endCol - startCol + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, false);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This script is run by OnEdit trigger. So, when you directly run this script, an error occurs. When you use this script, please edit the cells "C9:E20" of "Weekly Leaderboard" sheet. By this, the script is run. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)